# Exist any workaround for limit size of variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, web-scraping, export-to-csv, tampermonkey

I am trying to scrape some data from a website using Tumpermonkey Browser Add-on & JavaScript. The goal it's to 'export' parts of info into a .CSV/.txt file and then download it and Import into google SpreadSheet to do my calcs on the future.

My script is working when i run in a page with +/- 270 results/lines/rows.

Problem is when i go to the page with + than 2000 results/lines/row. For this page, I add more 1 variable to pick a "rarity link" class. BUT when scraping, the script/console stucks/loops on value/cicle +/-1065 results/lines/rows. And keeps in loop on that value (1065) with no data and don't finish.

I think is some problem about Variable size limit?!?.

I am some days thinking & work about a workaround for this, like replace the full HTTP link in a text Word if that link includes specific word, but without success, i am newer in JavaScript maybe the "logic" is wrong on my script.

Furthermore, I have tried at different browsers (Firefox and Brave) with last stable version of Tampermonkey, I have increased to disk.cache size and enable disk. Smart options to in 'about:config' browser menus.

Script Work:

1- Detect if contains X quantity of Pieces after page loaded

2- When reach all Pieces/End of page/Last Piece in the 'for' cicle. Will prepare the Variable (allDump) as a file and download it as .csv.

The Scrapping code and Download zone:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
 // Move BOTH: 0-2500 || 1-270
let piecetabsel = 0; // 0 = zone of +2000 rows Status: PROBLEM!   ||   1 = Zone of >280 Rows Status:OK
let totalpieces = 2500;  // 2500rows/line   ||   270rows/lines

let piecenamea = '';
let piecebonusa = '';
let piecepowera = '';
let themnrimage = '';
let pieceDumpFile = '';
let piecerarity = '';

var piecedumper = function(totalpieces){
    var countpieces = totalpieces - 1;
    var intra3 = setInterval(function(){
        for (koko; countpieces >= koko; koko++) {
            console.log("ID:" + koko);
            // >280 Pieces zone
            if (piecetabsel == 1){
                piecenamea = document.getElementsByClassName('piece-name')[koko].innerHTML;
                piecebonusa = document.getElementsByClassName('extra-value')[koko].innerHTML;
                piecepowera = document.getElementsByClassName('the-power')[koko].innerHTML;
                themnrimage = document.getElementsByClassName('photo-link')[koko].currentSrc;
                if(pieceDumpFile === ""){ pieceDumpFile = 'Common;' + piecenamea + ';' + piecebonusa + ';' + piecepowera + ';' + themnrimage + '\n'; }
                if(pieceDumpFile !== ""){ pieceDumpFile = pieceDumpFile + 'Common;' + piecenamea + ';' + piecebonusa + ';' + piecepowera + ';' + themnrimage + '\n'; }
            }
            // +2000 pieces zone - STUCK ZONE one 1065
            if (piecetabsel == 0){
                piecenamea = document.getElementsByClassName('collection-product-name')[koko].innerHTML;
                piecebonusa = document.getElementsByClassName('collection-bonus-amount')[koko].innerHTML.replace(/[+ ]/g, '').replace(".", ",");
                piecepowera = document.getElementsByClassName('power-value')[koko].innerHTML.replace(".", "");
                piecerarity = document.getElementsByClassName('collection-product-level-img-size-2')[koko].currentSrc;
                //
                // same has 270pieces zone ... BUT. with my workaround to decrease var size. NO SUCCESS
                if (piecerarity.includes('lv_2')) { pieceraritya = 'Uncommon'; }
                else if (piecerarity.includes('lv_3')) { pieceraritya = 'Rare'; }
                else if (piecerarity.includes('lv_4')) { pieceraritya = 'Epic'; }
                else if (piecerarity.includes('lv_5')) { pieceraritya = 'Legendary'; }
                else if (piecerarity.includes('lv_6')) { pieceraritya = 'mythic'; }
                else if (piecerarity.includes('lv_7')) { pieceraritya = 'SpecialOnes'; }
                else { pieceraritya = 'Common'; }
                if(pieceDumpFile === ""){ pieceDumpFile = pieceraritya + ';' + piecenamea + ';' + piecebonusa + ';' + piecepowera + '\n'; }
                if(pieceDumpFile !== ""){ pieceDumpFile = pieceDumpFile + pieceraritya + ';' + piecenamea + ';' + piecebonusa + ';' + piecepowera + '\n'; }
            }
        }
        clearInterval(intra3);
        var allDump='Rarity;Name;Power;Extra;Photo\n'+pieceDumpFile;
        downloadZone(allDump);
    }, 9000);
}
var downloadZone = function(allDump){
    var data=allDump;
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
    a.download = 'MyInfoScrapper.csv';
    console.log("Generate CSV File and Downloading");
    a.click();
}
piecedumper(totalpieces);
})();
```

I am Expecting some Ideas/workarounds/solution for my situation, i am out of ideas.
Maybe, something to do some 'File-Part1.csv.' 'File-Part2.csv' ?!

Comment: There is no inherent limit to variable sizes in JavaScript – the tab would crash with an out-of-memory error, but it shouldn't hang. There's some other bug in your script, I think.

Comment: What page are you running this script on? That'd help with debugging.

Comment: Hi @AKX Is a browser game, I have "hide/replace" some values on code from hidden some info from "obscure minds".
I am developing this with authorization from Devs of that game to do this (I need send them the code to they can check is not malicious). Is other way i can send you a youtube link for you see? hope you understand the reason of my "mistery"... :| Or maybe missiong some "output info" on Question?

Comment: Well, it really is hard to help without seeing the markup that this targets, etc. You could simplify the code by representing the data as an array of arrays (or an array of strings), and maybe, if needed, use blobs and [`createObjectURL`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to avoid the long data:// URL (that could be an issue indeed).